# Handle errors but stay subscribed to original Observable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Let's say I have an button and every time that button is tapped I would like to perform a network request and bind the results to a view on the main scheduler. I also need to deal with the chance that this network request might fail. Here was my original idea:

```
button.rx.tap.asObservable()
  .flatMap(networkRequest)
  .asDriver(onErrorRecover: handleError)
  .drive(uiComponent)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

What I want to happen is for a possible error to be handled by `handleError` and then make the request again when the button is tapped again. This does not work because in the event of an error, I am now subscribed to the `Driver` returned by `handleError`. The only other idea I have is to keep the signal an `Observable` and handle the error case and next case separately in the `subscribe`. This would also necessitate a `observeOn`. I was hoping for something a bit more elegant than that. Does anyone have an alternative approach to this use case?

**Edit**

I should also mention that one method that has worked for us was to handle the error in the `flatMap`.

```
button.rx.tap.asObservable()
  .flatMap {
    return networkRequest()
      .catchError(handleError)
  }
  .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: Driver.empty())
  .drive(uiComponent)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

However, it again seems less elegant than I would think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I will use `Result` type to wrap the return result and error that may occur.

You can convert to `Result` type in your `networkRequest()` method

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I believe if we wrap the error in a `Result` it only achieves the same thing as not converting to a `Driver`, and handling the `next` and `error` events differently in subscribing to the `Observable`.

Comment: Yeah I know what you want to achieve but I tried that before but didn't come up with a good solution just like you.
I ended up with the `Result` way which looks best to me.
I believe there is `onErrorResumeNext` operator which is what we both want but sadly this operator is not available in `RxSwift`